# Where did Jenkins find `groovy-html.template`?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, automation, continuous-integration, devops-services

I'm attaching a template in email using Jenkins. I've created a folder name `email-templates` under `.jenkins` and there I've placed my template with the name `build-report.groovy`.

Good thing is i can attach this template in email ext using `${SCRIPT, template="build-report.groovy"}` and i can see the expected data in email.

But if i use `${SCRIPT, template="groovy-html.template"}` i can also see the same template data with colors and styles.

I didn't have any template file with name `groovy-html.template` then from where Jenkins picked ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a part of email-ext Jenkins plugin and it's located inside of corresponding jar file.

You can see it in the source code:

https://github.com/jenkinsci/email-ext-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/hudson/plugins/emailext/templates/groovy-html.template

Comment: Thanks @daggett, Its really helpful.